# Wi-Fi drops at random times

Tags: wireless-networking

My home wi-fi network is randomly dropping (yellow mark and exclaimation sign in Windows terms). It's fixed as soon as I reconnect to that network, but it's super tilting and causes me a lot of frustration. What could be the problem here? Where should I look? I tried looking up some program to 1-click-reconnect but unfortunately didn't find one. (that would be enough of a solution for me, if you know how to do it, please do tell!)

Comment: There could be plenty of reasons. Could be a deauthentication attack, could be faulty hardware. It would be helpful if you would provide a capture of the Wi-Fi packets (e.g. using Wireshark) when this happens.

Comment: it happens at completely random times,do i need to have this turned on all the time?

Comment: Well you have to have it turned on when the connection gets disrupted. Make sure to capture the link layer, see https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN

Answer (score 0):

On the problem computer, update the wireless driver to the newest driver and then run TCP/IP Reset:

Open `cmd.exe` with Run as Administrator

Then: `netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt`

Then: `ipconfig /flushdns`

Then: restart the computer

Comment: did all of this, will try to test for a week or so and i'll try to report back

Comment: @John you can create numbered lists on this site by starting each line with 1. First item 2. Second item etc. It really helps with instructions like this. Each item gets automatically indented.